# Django: Form save method

Tags: django, django-forms, save, models

I have a form, working off different models and using a through (intermediate) model:

```
class CourseBooking(BaseModel):
    '''Intermediary model linking a person on a course with the related booking'''

    course = ForeignKey('ScheduledCourse')
    customer = ForeignKey('Customer')
    booking = ForeignKey('GroupBooking', blank=True, null=True)
```

The form is using a basic form instead of Model form, with the fields added in manually:

```
class CourseBookingForm(Form):

    course = ModelChoiceField(queryset=ScheduledCourse.objects.all())    
    title = CharField(
            max_length=255,
            widget=Select(choices=TITLE_CHOICES),
            required=False
            )
    gender = CharField(
            max_length=255,
            widget=Select(choices=GENDER_CHOICES),
            required=False
            )
    first_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = CharField( max_length=255)
    dob = DateField(required=False)    
    medical = CharField(required=False, widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '4'}))
    # miscellaneous notes
    notes = CharField(required=False, widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '4'}))
    email = EmailField(required=False)
    phone = CharField(required=False)
    address = CharField(
            max_length=8188,
            widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows':'4', 'cols':'50'}),
            required=False)
    city = CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    county = CharField(
            max_length=255, widget=Select(choices=COUNTY_CHOICES))
    postcode = CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    country = CharField(
            max_length=255,
            widget=Select(choices=COUNTRIES), required=False)
```

I want to create a save method in the `forms.py` which will save to the database. What I have at the moment (which is wrong) is and gives the error: `IntegrityError: null value in column "customer_id" violates not-null constraint`

```
def save(self):

    data = self.cleaned_data

    if self.cleaned_data['course']:
        crs = self.cleaned_data['course']
        course_booking = CourseBooking(course=crs)
    course_booking.save()

    course = CourseBooking.objects.create(course=data['course'])
    course.save()

    cust = Customer.objects.create(title=data['title'],
                                   gender=data['gender'],
                                   first_name=data['first_name'],
                                   surname=data['surname'],
                                   dob=data['dob'],
                                   notes=data['notes'],
                                   medical=data['medical'],
                                   content_object=cust,
                                   )
    cust.save()

    address = Address.objects.create(address=data['address'],
                      city=data['city'],
                      county=data['county'],
                      postcode =data['postcode'],
                      country=data['country'],
                      content_object=address,
                      )
    address.save()

    email = Email.objects.create(email=data['email'],
                                 content_object=email)
    email.save()

    phone = Phone.objects.create(number=data['phone'],
                  content_object=phone)
    phone.save()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call the code for creation of the `course` object **after** creating the `customer` object.

The issue is, the `ForeignKey` `customer` in `Course` model is required, and you have not set that field while creating the object.

You have a couple of other minor issues which I have fixed in the code. .

```
def save(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data

    course_booking = None
    if self.cleaned_data['course']:
        crs = self.cleaned_data['course']
        course_booking = CourseBooking(course=crs)
        course_booking.save()

    cust = Customer.objects.create(title=data['title'],
                                   gender=data['gender'],
                                   first_name=data['first_name'],
                                   surname=data['surname'],
                                   dob=data['dob'],
                                   notes=data['notes'],
                                   medical=data['medical'],
                                   content_object=cust,
                                   )
    #cust.save()

    course = CourseBooking.objects.create(course=data['course'], customer = cust)
    if course_booking:
        course.booking = course_booking

    #course.save()

    address = Address.objects.create(address=data['address'],
                      city=data['city'],
                      county=data['county'],
                      postcode =data['postcode'],
                      country=data['country'],
                      content_object=address,
                      )
    #address.save()

    email = Email.objects.create(email=data['email'],
                                 content_object=email)
    #email.save()

    phone = Phone.objects.create(number=data['phone'],
                  content_object=phone)
    #phone.save()
```

On another note, I would put this object creation logic in the view, rather than the model_form's `save` method.

Comment: Note that save() takes an optional `commit` arg ; you should handle it.